# Why can't I have mutable values in Rust in array elements?

Tags: rust

```rust
let sets = [
        &mut HashSet::<char>::new(),
        &mut HashSet::<char>::new(),
        &mut HashSet::<char>::new(),
    ];
```

Why can't the above be:

```rust
let sets = [
        mut HashSet::<char>::new(),
        mut HashSet::<char>::new(),
        mut HashSet::<char>::new(),
    ];
```

I don't need a mutable reference, just a mutable value.

I get a syntax error when I try this:

```rust
let sets = [
        mut HashSet::<char>::new(),
        mut HashSet::<char>::new(),
        mut HashSet::<char>::new(),
    ];
```

Comment: `let mut sets: [HashSet<char>; 3] = Default::default();` is a shorter/less repetitive way to initialize that, by the way.

Answer (score 8):

`mut` refers to if a variable is mutable, where as `&mut` refers to a mutable reference. So you can use `mut variable_name` or `&mut Type`, but not `mut Type`.

If you want the array to be mutable, you can specify it like this. This produces a mutable `HashSet<char>` array of length 3.

```rust
let mut sets = [
        HashSet::<char>::new(),
        HashSet::<char>::new(),
        HashSet::<char>::new(),
    ];
```

Comment: Exactly this. In the first example, you have an immutable array of type `[&mut HashSet]`. The elements of the array are "mutable references to `HashSet`". In the answer here, the elements of the array are of type `HashSet`, and the `sets` name is declared as mutable.